# gzip in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>

# Enable expirations
ExpiresActive On

# Default directive
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"

# My favicon
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year”

# Images
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"

# CSS
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month”

# Javascript
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"

</IfModule>

<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Connection keep-alive
</ifModule>


#Gzip - compress text, html, javascript, css, xml
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
</ifmodule>
#End Gzip
```

Gzip is not working, but everything else works. Server supports .htaccess file, but no matter what I do it won't compress my web site, http://kresimirpereglin.hostzi.com.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `mod_deflate` is loaded. The Gzip section is enclosed in a `<IfModule>` container so none of that gets applied unless `mod_deflate` is loaded.

You can check by looking in your httpd.conf file and you should see something like:

```
LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
```

Make sure it's uncommented.